# Intersection of subelements of multiple list of lists in dictionary

Tags: python, list, set

I have a number of lists of lists stored in a dictionary. I want to find the intersection of the sub-lists (i.e. `intersection of dict[i][j]) for all keys of the dictionary`. )

For example, if the dictionary stored sets of tuples instead, I could use the code:

```
set.intersection(*[index[key] for key in all_keys])
```

What is an efficient way to do this? One way I tried was to first convert each list of lists into a set of tuples and then taking the intersection of those, but this is rather clunky.

Example:

Suppose the dictionary of lists of lists is

```
dict = {} 
dict['A'] = [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'frankie']] 
dict['B'] = [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'chuck']]
dict['C'] = [[2, 'chuck'], [1, 'charlie']]
```

then I want to return

```
[1, 'charlie']
```

(maybe as a tuple, doesn't have to be list)

EDIT: I just found an okay way to do it, but it's not very 'pythonic'

```
def search(index, search_words): 
    rv = {tuple(t) for t in index[search_words[0]]}
    for word in search_words: 
        rv = rv.intersection({tuple(t) for t in index[word]})
    return rv
```

Comment: Can you give a sample?

Comment: Yup! Just added one -- thanks

Comment: Where is a dictionary involved?  Question title says dictionary

Comment: A, B, and C are stored in a dictionary. I'll edit to make clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call your dictionary of lists of lists `d`:

```
>>> d = {'A': [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'frankie']], 'B': [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'chuck']], 'C': [[2, 'chuck'], [1, 'charlie']]}
```

I am calling it `d` because `dict` is a builtin and we would prefer not to overwrite it.

Now, find the intersection:

```
>>> set.intersection( *[ set(tuple(x) for x in d[k]) for k in d ] )
set([(1, 'charlie')])
```

#### How it works

- `set(tuple(x) for x in d[k])`

  For key `k`, this forms a set out of tuples of the elements in `d[k]`.  Taking `k='A'` for example:

  ```
  >>> k='A'; set(tuple(x) for x in d[k])
  set([(2, 'frankie'), (1, 'charlie')])
  ```
- `[ set(tuple(x) for x in d[k]) for k in d ]`

  This makes a list of the sets from the step above.  Thus:

  ```
  >>> [ set(tuple(x) for x in d[k]) for k in d ]
  [set([(2, 'frankie'), (1, 'charlie')]),
   set([(2, 'chuck'), (1, 'charlie')]),
   set([(2, 'chuck'), (1, 'charlie')])]
  ```
- `set.intersection( *[ set(tuple(x) for x in d[k]) for k in d ] )`

  This gathers the intersection of the three sets as above:

  ```
  >>>set.intersection( *[ set(tuple(x) for x in d[k]) for k in d ] )
  set([(1, 'charlie')])
  ```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I needed. I tried doing something similar for awhile but my notation must have been off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
[item for item in A if item in B+C]
```

Comment: There will be a varying number of list of lists, and they are stored in a dictionary.

Comment: Can each list only have the item once, or can there be redundancy in a single list?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm pretty sure that each list will only have the item once... but it's scraped data though, so I'm not sure I would put my trust into that assumption.

Comment: Cuz if that was the case, you could just add all three lists, and us collections.count to see which has three.

Answer (score 1):

Your usecase demands the use of `reduce` function. But, quoting the [BDFL's take on reduce](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196),

> So now `reduce()`. This is actually the one I've always hated most, because, apart from a few examples involving `+` or `*`, almost every time I see a `reduce()` call with a non-trivial function argument, I need to grab pen and paper to diagram what's actually being fed into that function before I understand what the reduce() is supposed to do. So in my mind, the applicability of `reduce()` is pretty much limited to associative operators, and **in all other cases it's better to write out the accumulation loop explicitly.**

So, what you have got is already *'pythonic'*.

I would write the program like this

```
>>> d = {'A': [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'frankie']],
... 'B': [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'chuck']],
... 'C': [[2, 'chuck'], [1, 'charlie']]}
>>> values = (value for value in d.values())
>>> result = {tuple(item) for item in next(values)}
>>> for item in values:
...    result &= frozenset(tuple(items) for items in item)
>>> result
set([(1, 'charlie')])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict    
d = {'A': [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'frankie']], 'B': [[1, 'charlie'], [2, 'chuck']], 'C': [[2, 'chuck'], [1, 'charlie']]}

frequency = defaultdict(set)
for key, items in d.iteritems():
    for pair in items:
        frequency[tuple(pair)].add(key)
output = [
    pair for pair, occurrances in frequency.iteritems() if len(d) == len(occurrances)
]
print output
```