# how to find intersection?

Tags: python, intersection

I have two list.

```py
    red = [[2,2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
    
    blue = [[3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6]]
```

how to find intersection in this case?

I know what is the set.

but, In this case... I think it can not to do to use list.

list in list... how can i do?

```py
[[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
[[3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-e0a8e962ef62> in <module>()
     11     print(list(red))
     12     print(list(blue))
---> 13     intersection = len(list(set(red) & set(blue)))
     14     print(list(set(red) & set(blue)))
     15     print(set(list(red)) & set(list(blue)))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection of subelements of multiple list of lists in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145319/intersection-of-subelements-of-multiple-list-of-lists-in-dictionary) [that's about values in a dict; but the values are lists of lists, so it's pretty similar]

Comment: To Nelewout // WOWOWOWOWOW you guys are so kind... I'm deeply touched...

Answer (score 1):

Sets can only contain hashable data, and lists are not hashable since they're mutable. On the other hand, tuples are perfectly hashable.

```
red_set = frozenset(tuple(x) for x in red)
blue_set = frozenset(tuple(x) for x in blue)

intersection_set = red_set & blue_set
intersection_list = list(list(x) for x in intersection_set)
```

If you don't mind working with tuples, you can leave it in the form `intersection_set` and it'll work just fine. But the last line gets it back to the original "list of lists" representation you started with.

Note that `set` would work here too, but since we never change them, `frozenset` states our intentions a bit better.

Comment: wow... really thank you... actually I didn't know "frozenset"... sosososo kind!! have a nice day!!